# Why is $B−p$ a multiplicatively closed subset of $B$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[image]

In the second proof, how to show $A_p\to B_p$ is injective? Why is $B-p$  a multiplicatively closed subset of $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $B_p$ does not refer to the localization of $B$ as a ring with respect to the prime ideal $p\subset B$ (indeed $p$ may not be a prime ideal of $B$, or even an ideal at all).  Rather, it refers to the localization $B_p$ of $B$ as an $A$-algebra.  That is, it is $A_p\otimes_A B$, or if you like, the localization of $B$ with respect to the multiplicatively closed subset $A\setminus p$.  The fact that $A_p\to B_p$ is injective then just follows from the fact that localization with respect to $p$ is an exact functor (on the category of $A$-modules), since the map $A_p\to B_p$ is just the localization of the injection $A\to B$ with respect to $p$.